# Php file shows as plain text in Chromium

Tags: apache2, 22.04, php

ive upgraded recently from 20.04 to 22.04.1

Im facing that when im executing the typical file phpinfo file,containing only:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

instead of showing the usual php info tables it shows:

Firefox -> blank page
Chromium -> text plain with the instruction.

Some info:

My version of php is 8.1

```
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
FFI
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pgsql
Phar
posix
pspell
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache




eduardo@MiPcLinux:/var/www/html/moodle$ php -v
PHP 8.1.2 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2022 13:08:39) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.2, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Did you actually install and enable the PHP module for Apache?  If you did not install `libapache2-mod-php` and then `a2enmod php` afterwards then you won't have PHP available for Apache to use.  The PHP CLI `php-cli` package does NOT mean you have PHP installed proper for Apache to use, therefore your CLI `php` calls don't help us in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reinstall libapache2-mod-php and then a2dismod php7.4 to be sure and finally a2enmod php8.1....

Just in case i then restart apache and worked....S

trange because i tried to install liabpache2-mod-php and system answered that the package was already installed ( as i came from an upgrade from 20.04.5 perhaps). So